# Return field even if specific field value isn't available

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this bool query:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must_not": [
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "*multiparttype.doNotDisplay",
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    ],
    "should": [
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "multiparttype",
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "*multiparttype.oldValue",
          "boost": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "*multiparttype.newValue",
          "boost": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It return data if ES has following structure. If a document exist like below, this query will work and return this documents

```
multiparttype{
  oldValue: "YY",
  newValue:"XXX",
  type:10
}
```

But if document just have this:

```
multiparttype{
  type:10
}
```

OR

```
multiparttype{

}
```

Above query wont return this document

How can i make it possible??

Comment: Clarification: _source doesn't contain multiparttype and hence it is not coming, correct ?

Comment: I have updated description, pls have a look

Comment: For your use case "multiparttype" doesn't exists & multiparttype = {} are 2 different things ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElasticSearch null\_value with an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840837/elasticsearch-null-value-with-an-object)

Comment: if its `multiparttype{
  oldValue: "YY",
  newValue:"XXX",
  type:10
}` query works fine BUT if it is `multiparttype{
  type:10
}` or `multiparttype{
}` or if `multiparttype`  doesnt exit then my query doesnt work.

Comment: Have you used "minimum_should_match" >1  with should clause? I don't see a reason why "multiparttype{
  type:10
}" shouldn't be part of the result

Comment: yes currently `"multiparttype{ type:10 }"` is not getting returned

Comment: Which version of ES are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your problem, you need to use a match_all which will match against all documents, which would return all documents with a score of "1.0".

The following data was in the index:

1. multiparttype = { "oldValue" : "versionX","newValue" : "versionY"}
2. multiparttype = { "oldValue" : "versionX","newValue" : "versionY"}
3. empty_field : "test",multiparttype : {}
4. multiparttype" = {"type" : "typetest"}

The following query was corrected taking into account the boost which can be changed based on the requirements.

```
    "query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
                {
                    "match_all": {}
                    },
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "multiparttype.oldValue",
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "multiparttype.newValue",
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "*multiparttype.doNotDisplay"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

The following response will be generated:

```
"hits" : {
"total" : {
  "value" : 4,
  "relation" : "eq"
},
"max_score" : 3.0,
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "stackoverflow-field",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "7Qg7TnQB3IIDvL59KA7i",
    "_score" : 3.0,
    "_source" : {
      "multiparttype" : {
        "oldValue" : "versionX",
        "newValue" : "versionY"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "stackoverflow-field",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1wmWTnQB3IIDvL59lAAL",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "multiparttype" : {
        "type" : "typetest"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "stackoverflow-field",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "tQmbTnQB3IIDvL59Zgy7",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "empty_field" : "test"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "stackoverflow-field",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "tQmcTnQB3IIDvL59fA8Z",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "empty_field" : "test",
      "multiparttype" : { }
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

Documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html